# Swipe to delete element + sub-elements of the list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My objective is to implement a swipe to delete feature in a list that contains two hierarchical levels of items A and B, one containing the other. A list could be :

- A

  - B
  - B
- A

  - B

What I succeed to do with my `recycler adapter` is to implement this list with the swipe to delete, however every item (A or B) is an element of the list. To distinguish the hierarchy, I just displayed the item B with a left margin.

As every item is considered as an element of the list, if you swipe to delete the element A, the business logic deletes all the elements B associated to the A, and if you swipe to delete an element B, just that element is deleted.

What I would like to do, is that when I swipe an element A, I'd like every B associated to it to be swiped at the same time, just with A's finger movment. I don't know what I should do to implement that.
I don't know if what say sounds clear, but it's a simple effect that I struggle to explain ^^

```java
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,  ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                            // Get RecyclerView item from the ViewHolder
                            View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

                            Paint p = new Paint();
                            //Bitmap icon;

                            if (dX > 0) {
                                Bitmap icon = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);
                                /* Set the color for positive displacement */
                                p.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);

                                // Draw Rect with varying right side, equal to displacement dX
                                c.drawRect((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,
                                        (float) itemView.getBottom(), p);

                                c.drawBitmap(icon,
                                        (float) dX - convertDpToPx(40),
                                        (float) itemView.getTop() + ((float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop() - icon.getHeight())/2,
                                        p);
                            }
                            // Fade out the view as it is swiped out of the parent's bounds
                            final float alpha = 1.0f - Math.abs(dX) / (float) viewHolder.itemView.getWidth();
                            viewHolder.itemView.setAlpha(alpha);
                            viewHolder.itemView.setTranslationX(dX);
                            // If negative displacement is needed
                            /*else {
                                *//* Set the color for negative displacement *//*
                                p.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
                                // Draw Rect with varying left side, equal to the item's right side plus negative displacement dX
                                c.drawRect((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),
                                        (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom(), p);
                            }*/

                            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                        }
                    }
```